# No Database selected when retrieving from mysql website

Tags: java, mysql

I have a mysql database that I am trying to retrieve from our website host (godaddy).  I followed a format that seems to be right but it tells me that:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        // STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        // STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM item_master";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  //<-- This is where the error is.

        // STEP 5: Extract data from result set
        while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            int id = rs.getInt("id");

            // Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
        }
...
}
```

I did a print statement of the conn to maybe think the connection could of been null and was shown this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2a6*****
```

Anyone have any ideas what could cause something like this?

Comment: plz show the values of `DB_URL`, at least the format if its privacy is important.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your URL for your database should include your database name. This is normally your URL followed by a "/DBNAME".

`String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";`

Where "mydb" is your database name.

Comment: This is the DB url that I have: jdbc:mysql://SLibdev.db.9969424.hostedresource.com

Comment: so it's missing the port and the database scheme name. This is definietly the answer, +1

Comment: @AdriánLópez So this would be the format?

jdbc:mysql://hostedresource.com:9969424/SLibdev.db

Comment: Can't be, that number is too big to be a port

Comment: the default is 3306 try with that or ask your provider

Comment: You should check with your hosting company for the correct URL. If you have access to PHPMyAdmin that will tell you the address and the database name. You should also ask the provider if they will allow external connections to the database as I assume you are running your Java code on your local machine.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I was able to connect!!! :D.  I wish I could give you all some points for this.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of DB_URL? As far as I am aware, the URL needs to be of the form:
"WEBURL/DATABASENAME:PORT"
Are you just trying to connect to the WEBURL, without specifying a DATABASE?

Comment: This is the DB url that I have:

jdbc:mysql://SLibdev.db.9969424.hostedresource.com

Comment: Ah, yes, you are indeed correct. The format shoudl therefore be "WEBURL/DATABASENAME:PORT"

Comment: Ah yes, you are indeed correct. The right format is therefore "WEBURL:PORT/DATABASENAME". I believe a typical port for mysql is 3306. So you would want something like "SLibdev.db.9969424.hostedresource.com:3306/DBNAME"

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I was able to connect!!! :D.  I wish I could give you all some points for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Just run one more query (before your 'SELECT' statement) to connect to your database.

First:

```
sql = "USE <yourdatabase>";

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

And after:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM item_master";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```