# java.sql.SQLException: No database selected Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I use GlassFish4.1, Intellij IDEA, MySQL. When I started project in browser on a page I see error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@676ed7c5 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@76a2117c expression = bookDAOImpl.books, resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'main' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
root cause

org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@676ed7c5 targetAction = [EvaluateAction@76a2117c expression = bookDAOImpl.books, resultExpression = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'main' of flow 'main' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'
root cause

org.springframework.binding.expression.EvaluationException: An ELException occurred getting the value for expression 'bookDAOImpl.books' on context [class org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl]
root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1021E:(pos 0): A problem occurred whilst attempting to access the property 'books': 'Unable to access property 'books' through getter'
root cause

org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Unable to access property 'books' through getter
root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
      "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

      <mapping resource="com.sombra.test.training.entities/Author.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="com.sombra.test.training.entities/Book.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="com.sombra.test.training.entities/Genre.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="com.sombra.test.training.entities/Publisher.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="com.sombra.test.training.entities/Vote.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration></hibernate-configuration>
```

BookDAOImpl.java:

```
@Repository
public class BookDAOImpl implements BookDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private List<Book> books;


@Transactional
@Override
public List<Book> getBooks() {

    books = (List<Book>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Book.class)
            .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

    return books;
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/Library"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.sombra.test.training"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Call method in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<view-state id="main">

    <on-render>
        <evaluate expression="bookDAOImpl.books"/>
    </on-render>

</view-state>

</flow>
```

Add web.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>


        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>



    </web-app>
```

GlassFish Log:

```
[2016-09-08T12:03:00.695+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1473325380695] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:530)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.PreparedStatementWrapper40.executeQuery(PreparedStatementWrapper40.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:932)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1863)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:365)
    at com.sombra.test.training.dao.impl.BookDAOImpl.getBooks(BookDAOImpl.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy280.getBooks(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectivePropertyAccessor$OptimalPropertyAccessor.read(ReflectivePropertyAccessor.java:628)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:372)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionList.execute(ActionList.java:154)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.render(ViewState.java:291)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.refresh(ViewState.java:242)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:220)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.handle(JsfFlowHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Comment: Share your web.xml. also i hope you mentioned all required dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Remove `hibernate.current_session_context_class` from your hibernate configuration and all your `hibernate.connection` properties are useless due to the fact you are injecting a `DataSource`.

Comment: Also your dao should, ideally, be annotated with `@Repository` and you shouldn't assign the list of books to an instance variable. You should directly return the result of the query.

Comment: If you want more assistance as mentioned share the `web.xml` and also include the actual stacktrace not what you see on screen.

Comment: I added web.xml

Comment: And I updated hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: I changed annotation to @Repository. After that as I changed file hibernate.cfg.xml error change to java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Comment: And I added glassfish log

Comment: I solved my problem. I use GlassFish for dataSource bean, but in configurations GlassFish I allowed mistake in URL, URL was:jdbc:mysql://:3306/  I changed it to jdbc:mysql://:3306/sombratestdb  and everything work )  Thank you all for your advice )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Database selected when retrieving from mysql website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844372/no-database-selected-when-retrieving-from-mysql-website)